# ZXING android QR Code Mode 1 and Mode 2 Type

Tags: android, android-studio, qr-code, zxing, mode

I've created and android application that can generate and scan qr code the problem is when i generate a qr code it can only be read horizontally using a zxing qr scanner but when i find a sample qr code on google it can read even on vertical format

I search and I find out that there are 2 types of basic qr code MODE1 and MODE2 I conclude that zxing can only generate MODE1

Is there any way that I can change the type of generated QR Code using zxing to MODE2 so that the scanner can read it horizontallly or vertically?

thanks.

here is the code i use to generate

```
MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();

            try{
                BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(text.getText().toString(), BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,200,200);

                BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
                Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }catch (WriterException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set it as the [EncodedHintType QR_Version](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/EncodeHintType.html), in the hints parameter of the [overloaded encoding function](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/MultiFormatWriter.html#encode-java.lang.String-com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat-int-int-java.util.Map-)

```
public BitMatrix encode(String contents,
                    BarcodeFormat format,
                    int width,
                    int height,
                    Map<EncodeHintType,?> hints)
             throws WriterException
```

//edit 
Based on your code, it could look like this. But be aware, I have not tested the code.

```
MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();

        try{
            Map<EncodeHintType, Object> hints = new EnumMap<EncodeHintType, Object>(EncodeHintType.class);
            hints.put(EncodeHintType.QR_VERSION, 2);
            BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(text.getText().toString(), BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,200,200, hints);

            BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
            Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }catch (WriterException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply where do it on my code?
Thank you so much.

Comment: I tried your code but it seems like EncodeHintType.QR_VERSION has been depricated on the library i imported the library but when i search for the QR_VERSION nothing comes up

Thanks for your help anyways :D

Comment: Which version of zxing do you use?